# Writing to file - void issue

Tags: c++

I have a void type function displaying a couple of integers to the console. I want these integers to be written to a file. This is the function I'm talking about:

```
void inorder(node *root)
{
    if(root)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        std::cout << root->key << " ";
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}
```

I'm aware of the fact that it could have been done if I'd return array of integers. But it would complicate my code, I would have to add some kind of a count argument etc.

Is this possible to write the outcome of this function to a file?

Answer (score 3):

You could trivially change the function to take a reference to an `std::ostream`, then pass it an `ofstream` or `std::cout` depending on whether you want to write to a file or to the standard output:

```
void inorder(node *root, std::ostream& os)
{
  if(root)
  {
    inorder(root->left, os);
    os << root->key << " ";
    inorder(root->right, os);
  }
}
```

then

```
node* root = ....;

// write to stdout
inorder(root, std::cout);

// write to a file
std::ofstream myfile("myfile.txt");
inordet(root, myfile);
```

Comment: I see what you mean, it works, thanks. Eventually if I'd have to allow outputting this to the console I could make an overloading function...

Comment: @user2252786 Why overloading? `inorder(root, std::cout)` already does the console output.